# INVALID_CHARGER in BatteryManager

Tags: android

When checking the source of BatteryManager there is an extra which is called `EXTRA_INVALID_CHARGER` with `@hide` annotation. This is info that might be usefull for me.
When checking this class at Android Developers I can see that this field is not shown there.

I've read the short doc about this. Does anybody knows exactly what does it do? since when it is supported and if it is reliable?

Comment: The docs here: https://cells-source.cs.columbia.edu/plugins/gitiles/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-4.3_r2.1/core/java/android/os/BatteryManager.java state this: `/**
     * Extra for {@link android.content.Intent#ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED}:
     * Int value set to nonzero if an unsupported charger is attached
     * to the device.
     * {@hide}
     */
    public static final String EXTRA_INVALID_CHARGER = "invalid_charger";`. It'd be nice if someone can clarify this.